# Empty set is perfect?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it right to say that the empy set is perfect? It contains no point and for a perfect set every point in the set should be limit point, so how to prove this if it is right? Please help.

Comment: Can you disprove it? Can you find a point that is not a limit point?

Comment: Is there a point in the empty set that is *not* a limit point?

Comment: vacuous truth maybe?  see second section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set

Comment: In general, statements of the form $\forall xP(x)$ are true for the empty set. This is because a statement must be true or false. If this statement was false then $\exists x\neg P(x)$ would be true but no $x$ can exist in the empty set.

Comment: Or may be can we say that an empty set is not perfect at the same time ? Like we are saying empty set is open aswell as closed.

Comment: A set can be open and closed but it cannot be open and not open.

Comment: Most definitions of *perfect set*, including what you seem to be using, allow the empty set to be perfect. However, it is very often the case (especially in real analysis, iteration theory, quasiconformal mapping theory, etc.) that authors assume (often without explicitly saying this) that "perfect set" excludes the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

You need to carefully read the definition of perfect set you are using.  The definition in Wikipedia is "a subset of a topological space is perfect if it is closed and has no isolated points", which I think is standard.  The empty set is required to be closed in all topological spaces and has no points at all, isolated or not, so it fits.  Sometimes "too simple" cases are excluded in a definition, which is why you have to check.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the empty set does not have any elements.

We can reword it to say that it has $0$ elements.

All its $0$ elements are limit points because otherwise we have to show at least one element which is not a limit point.

Thus the empty set is perfect.

Empty set is very tricky, do not be surprised by its perfectness!

Answer (score 0):

Definition of a perfect set:

A set $A$ is perfect if
$$
\forall x\,(x\in A\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\text{$\,x$ is an accumulation point of $A$})\tag{1}
$$
Is the empty set perfect?

Is the empty set was not perfect, the would be an $x$, such that
$$
x\in \varnothing\,\,\text{AND $\,x$ is NOT an accumulation point of $\varnothing$}
$$
But the above is FALSE, since "$x\in \varnothing$" is FALSE.

Hence, $(1)$ is VALID.